# Scipy leastsq() function overhead

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares

I am working on an image analysis program and I have narrowed down my bottleneck to attempts to fit a 2D gaussian to a small window (20x20) pixels many times. 90% of the execution time is spent in this code.

I am using the code given in the scipy cookbook for this problem:

```
   def gaussian(height, center_x, center_y, width_x, width_y):
           """Returns a gaussian function with the given parameters"""
        width_x = float(width_x)
        width_y = float(width_y)
        return lambda x,y: height*exp(
                    -(((center_x-x)/width_x)**2+((center_y-y)/width_y)**2)/2)


def moments(data):
    """Returns (height, x, y, width_x, width_y)
    the gaussian parameters of a 2D distribution by calculating its
    moments """
    total = data.sum()
    X, Y = indices(data.shape)
    x = (X*data).sum()/total
    y = (Y*data).sum()/total
    col = data[:, int(y)]
    width_x = sqrt(abs((arange(col.size)-y)**2*col).sum()/col.sum())
    row = data[int(x), :]
    width_y = sqrt(abs((arange(row.size)-x)**2*row).sum()/row.sum())
    height = data.max()
    return height, x, y, width_x, width_y


def fitgaussian(data):
    """Returns (height, x, y, width_x, width_y)
    the gaussian parameters of a 2D distribution found by a fit"""
    params = moments(data)
    errorfunction = lambda p: ravel(gaussian(*p)(*indices(data.shape)) -
                                 data)
    p, success = optimize.leastsq(errorfunction, params, maxfev=50, ftol=1.49012e-05)
    return p
```

I was able to cut the execution time in half by combining the errorfunction() and gaussian() functions so every time leastsq() calls errorfunction() there is one function call instead of two.

This leads me to believe that most of the remaining execution time is spent tied up in function call overhead as the leastsq() algorithm calls errorfunction().

Is there any way to reduce this function call overhead? I am at a loss since leastsq() takes a function as an input.

I apologize in advance if my description is confusing, I am a mechanical engineer by training and I'm learning Python as I go. Please let me know if there is any other information that would be helpful.

Comment: if what you fit is really a gaussian, do you actually need a call to `leastsq`--- can't you just calculate the moments, which you already do.

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't checked this, thank you for the suggestion! A quick look suggests that most of the time the calculated moments and final fitted gaussian differ by less then 10%. I'm going to try just using those in my algorithm to see how well it works and I'll check back in.

Comment: Well, I'm back. Seems that using the moments is good enough. Thanks Zhenya!

Comment: Zhenya should probably post their recommendation as an answer, as it does seem to have answered the question...

Answer (score 1):

Since exp is monotonic, you could use the logarithm of the gaussian as your error function, e.g.

```
def log_gaussian(height, center_x, center_y, width_x, width_y):
    """Returns a gaussian function with the given parameters"""
    width_x = float(width_x)
    width_y = float(width_y)
    log_height = log(height)
    return lambda x,y: (log_height - 
             (((center_x-x)/width_x)**2 - ((center_y-y)/width_y)**2)/2)
```

This will result in 1 call to log per iteration, rather than 1 call to exp per dataset row each iteration.